# How to optimize large database requests

Tags: database, optimization, hierarchical-data

I am working with a database that contains information (measurements) about ships. The ships send an update with their position, fuel use, etc. So an entry in the database looks like this

```
| measurement_id | ship_id | timestamp     | position | fuel_use |
| key            | f_key   | dd-mm-yy hh:ss| lat-lon  | in l/km  |
```

A new one of these entries gets added for every ship every second so the amount of entries in the database gets large very fast.

What I need for the application I am working on is not the information for one second but rather cumulative data for 1 minute, 1 day, or even 1 year. For example the total fuel use over a day, the distance traveled in a year, or the average fuel use per day over a month.

To get that and calculate that from this raw data is unfeasible, you would have to get 31,5 million records from the server to calculate the distance traveled in a year.

What I thought was the smart thing to do is combining entries into one bigger entry. For example get 60 measurements and combine them into 1 minute measurement entry in a separate table. By averaging the fuel use, and by summing the distance traveled between two entries. A minute entry would then look like this.

```
| min_measurement_id | ship_id | timestamp  | position    | distance_traveled     | fuel_use     |
| new key            |same ship| dd-mm-yy hh| avg lat-lon | sum distance_traveled | avg fuel_use |
```

This process could then be repeated to work with hours, days, months, years. This way a query for a week could be done by requesting only 7 queries, or if I want hourly details 168 entries. Those look like way more usable numbers to me.

The new tables can be filled by querying the original database every 10 minutes, that data then fills the minute table, which in turn updates the hours table, etc.

However this seems to be a lot of management and duplication of almost the same data, with constantly the same operation being done.

So what I am interested in is if there is some way of structuring this data. Could it be sorted hierarchically (after all seconds, days, minutes are pretty hierarchical) or are there other ways to optimize this?

This is the first time I am using a database this size so I also did not really know what to look for on the internet.

Comment: You'd have to design the system properly, so the per-second data can't get out-of-sync with the summary data.  With care, yes it's perfectly valid to work with larger-granularity cached averages.  You'd have to figure out what higher level stuff needs to see:  e.g. maybe cache a bounding box of positions per minute, not just an avg. position.  I'm not an expert in this, but what you suggest sounds reasonable.  Indexes duplicate / summarize data too, and they're essential to avoid linear searches.  The difference is that you're prob. going to have to write code for the custom summaries you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregates are common in data warehouses so your approach to group data is fine. Yes, you are duplicating some of the data, but you'll get the speed benefit.